# Query to return the registers that the table doesn't have

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a 268 registry list and I would like to see which of them are not in the table. I  used not it but it returns the other registers of the table and not the ones I have to see.

Suppous I have a table with ID:  1,2,3,4

I have a list (to build the where clause) with ID: 0,1,4,5,99

I need to build a PL/SQL query that return numbers 0, 5 and 99.

I have tried the following:

```
Select * from myTable where ids not in ('0,1,4,5,99')
```

But this will return all registers of the table and not only the ones I want. I know I need to put this list I have as a refference to return it but I have no Idea how to do it.

Comment: Show whatever you came up with so far.

Comment: "I need to build a PL/SQL query that return numbers 0, 5 and 99." - select 0,5,99;    comon Dan, we're a community of developers supporting each other, not a free 'write a script for me' service.

Comment: @PM77-1 I have updated the main question.. I'm sorry being so dumb on SQL, lol. I know that I need to add another select  inside the refference but I really don't know how to perform it

Comment: @Twelfth you are right  but I really don't see how the code I came up with would help someone helping me doing this. Anyway, I have edited the main question with smth near I have tried

Comment: Since you say `PL/SQL` I assume it's `Oracle`, right?

Comment: What is the format of your *registry list*?  Can you load it into the table?

Comment: @PM77-1 its a string based list, like the sample. I have only rights to perform selects

Comment: OK. I posted the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work for `Oracle 11g`.  The idea to use [`XMLTABLE`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions253.htm#SQLRF52052) was *borrowed* from [Oracle: Comma Separated String To Rows 11g](http://nimishgarg.blogspot.com/2010/06/oracle-comma-seprated-string-to-rows.html) blog post.

```
WITH numbers AS 
   (
     SELECT '0, 1, 4, 5, 99' numberstring FROM dual
   ),  
     registry AS
   (
     SELECT (column_value).getnumberval() register
     FROM numbers, xmltable(numberstring) 
   )     
SELECT r.register
FROM registry r
LEFT JOIN Table1 t ON r.register = t.id
WHERE t.id IS NULL;
```

See working [**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/dc25d/3) demo.

---

Solution for a **string of strings**:

```
WITH strings AS 
   (
     SELECT      
      '"LOOKUP - 0971 - 2135",
       "LOOKUP - 0001 - 2424"' numberstring FROM dual
   ),  
     registry AS
   (
     SELECT (column_value).getStringVal() register
     FROM strings, xmltable(numberstring) 
   )     
SELECT r.register
FROM registry r
LEFT JOIN X_LANE t ON r.register = t.x_lane_gid
WHERE t.x_lane_gid IS NULL;
```

*String of strings* [**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/4a069/3)

Comment: I have done some changes to fit my needs but Im getting some problems. Can you help me? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/4a069/2

Comment: You were almost there. Just needed `"` around individual strings.